# Wifi doesn't work after suspend in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, 17.10

I tried all the solution available online that targeted the issue with ubuntu 16.04 users with no result in the case of ubuntu 17.10.

I tried using

```
  $ sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service

   $ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Also ran this script

```
#/etc/systemd/system/wifi-resume.service
#sudo systemctl enable wifi-resume.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

None of these methods worked. This issue never happened when I was working with ubuntu 17.04, I started getting these issues right after the update to ubnutu 17.10

This is all of my wireless driver related info

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 17 Feb 2018 16:36 EET +0200

Booted last: 17 Feb 2018 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, i8042.reset, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu on Xorg

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2297]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wl                   6447104  0
cfg80211              610304  1 wl
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 551  bytes 87017 (87.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 551  bytes 87017 (87.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.221  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::3222:415a:b45:19cb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7262  bytes 3293065 (3.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 2534
        TX packets 6348  bytes 1200856 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XPhone"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'XPhone' [AC1]>   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       948     1  0 16:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Limited
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.271 (r587334)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlo1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     XPhone
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       3c467896-2bd7-471a-a368-f68296558570
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     58 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,5}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   72fc3cfb-d9c9-42b7-8106-010bcb6b2edb | GUC-WiFi
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   3c467896-2bd7-471a-a368-f68296558570 | XPhone
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.43.221/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.43.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.43.221
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.43.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1518881025
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = logician-724
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.43.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.43.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3222:415a:b45:19cb/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:09:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID          BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
XPhone        <MAC 'XPhone' [AC1]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       yes     * 
--            <MAC '--' [AN2]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  65      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
GUC-WiFi      <MAC 'GUC-WiFi' [AN3]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
TE-Data       <MAC 'TE-Data' [AN4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
TEdata3D0B76  <MAC 'TEdata3D0B76' [AN5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--            <MAC '--' [AN6]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
GUC-WiFi      <MAC 'GUC-WiFi' [AN7]>  Infra  7     2442 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
GUC-WiFi      <MAC 'GUC-WiFi' [AN8]>  Infra  13    2472 MHz  54 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Blue Sky]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Blue Sky | type=wifi | permissions=user:logician:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Blue Sky
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=AndroidAP
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GUC-WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GUC-WiFi | type=wifi | permissions=user:logician:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=GUC-WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/TEdata9767E1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=TEdata9767E1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=TEdata9767E1
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/XPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=XPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=XPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Cairo (based on set time zone)

global
country EG: DFS-ETSI
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlo1      24 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'XPhone' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"XPhone"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     E179A1F6EAA13B7BC9AF7C6
depends:        cfg80211
name:           wl
vermagic:       4.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     A5EDD7467E172A70410EBCD
depends:        
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   16.237649] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   16.237652] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   17.754166] wl 0000:08:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   37.746157] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[  814.292676] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : 

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Does `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` make any difference?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: exactly same problem here, actually I can ping router but I can not ping internet. When `traceroute` internet, it use 169.254.x.x network which is absolutely wrong.